# Error: (195) expression syntax in MPLAB X IDE with PIC18F2420

Tags: syntax, pic, mplab

I have converted a project from MPLAB 8 to MPLAB X IDE - I believe I have the correct project properties but I am getting a syntax error for this line - anyone know what it could be as I am not sure

```
Temp = (u32)TEMP_TABLE[i][1] - (Temp / (u32));
```

Comment: As posted: `Temp = (u32)TEMP_TABLE[i][1] - (Temp / (u32));` is a syntax error as the type (u32) does not have any actual value in C. Did you intend something like:`Temp = (u32)TEMP_TABLE[i][1] - (Temp / sizeof(u32));` ?